# Show more elements on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show 5 elements on my page and then have a function to load/show 5 more and this process can continue until there is no more hidden elements left.

I have created a fiddle to show you what I have done so far: https://jsfiddle.net/89v781rL/2/

Currently, when the button is clicked, all the hidden elements are shown at the same time which is not what I want. I need to add 5 more elements to the ones that are in display at the time..

I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
$('#grid li').not(':visible').each( function() {    
  $("#grid").children(":gt(4)").hide();
});
```

This is my full working code:

```
$("#grid").children(":gt(4)").hide();

$('#sales').click(function() {
    $('#grid li').not(':visible').each( function() {
      $(this).slideDown();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve what you need by using `slice()` to get the next 5 hidden elements and calling `slideDown()` on them. Also note that you can use CSS's `:nth-child` to hide the elements instead of JS so that you avoid the FOUC on load. Try this:

```js
$('#sales').click(function() {
  $('#grid li:hidden').slice(0, 5).slideDown();
});
```

```css
#grid li:nth-child(n+6) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="grid effect-2 cols" id="grid">
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">11</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">12</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">13</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">14</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">15</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">16</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">17</a></li>
</ul>

<button id="sales">
  Show more
</button>
```

Comment: This is perfect. Out of interest, can I also do something like this:  $('#grid li').not(':visible').slice(0, 5).addClass('some-className;);

Comment: Absolutely. You can call any jQuery method on the result.